# Получение списка ячеек всех таблиц, используя BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть код, который парсит все таблицы с сайта, которые только может найти:

```
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find_all('table')
    res = []
    for row in table:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        print(cols)
    return res
```

Я ищу все таблицы, затем ищу в них тэг `td` и записываю результат в список.

Есть проблема с тем, что если я обращаюсь к `cols[1].text`, то я увижу первый элемент каждой таблицы, а мне нужно получить первый элемент для всех таблиц.

Допустим, есть таблицы вида:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="monitoring-td">1</td>
            <td class="monitoring-td">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="monitoring-td">3</td>
            <td class="monitoring-td">4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="monitoring-td">5</td>
            <td class="monitoring-td">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="monitoring-td">7</td>
            <td class="monitoring-td">8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

При выполнении моего кода: `print(cols[1].text)`
я получу ответ: `2 6`, а требуется только `2`,
а при запуске `print(cols[5].text)` я вообще получу ошибку, хотя требуется `6`

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста пример того, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: я хочу получить список, который не будет начинаться с нуля при переходе на вторую таблицу, затем на третью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого достаточно просто сохранить их в один список:

```
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find_all('table')
    all_cols = []
    for row in table:
        table_cols = row.find_all('td')
        all_cols.extend(cols)
    return all_cols
```

Насколько я понял, переменная `res` у вас для этого и была заведена. Я переименовал её и использовал для сохранения всех столбцов.

Также я убрал лишний вывод внутри функции.

Comment: спасибо, а то я уже под вечер на код смотрю как баран на новые ворота...